# How to check if string is null or not?

Tags: apex, string

Is my below condition to compare the string is correct? I have data in all the 6 strings but still all my records are not going inside if loop. Is there any other way to check string null,blank condition?

```
if((txtImportSection1 != null && txtImportSection1 != '') &&
        (txtImportSection2 != null && txtImportSection2 !='') &&
        (txtImportSection3 != null && txtImportSection3 !='') &&
        (txtImportSection4 != null && txtImportSection4 !='') &&
        (txtImportSection5 != null && txtImportSection5 != '') &&
        (txtImportSection6 != null && txtImportSection6 != '')){
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of checking for null and `''`. Use System methods from `String` class.

```
if (String.isNotBlank(txtImportSection1) && 
        String.isNotBlank(txtImportSection2) && 
        String.isNotBlank(txtImportSection3) && 
        String.isNotBlank(txtImportSection4) && 
        String.isNotBlank(txtImportSection5) && 
        String.isNotBlank(txtImportSection6)) {
    //code
}
```

`String.isNotBlank` checks for both `!= null` and `!= ''` and `!= ' '` internally and return true or false.

From Docs:

> isNotBlank(inputString) 
> **Returns true if the specified String is not whitespace, not empty (''), and not null; otherwise, returns false.**

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way to do this, with a bit less typing, is to (ab)use a Set.

Add everything to the set, remove nulls and blanks, and check to see if the set is empty or not.

```java
Set<String> givenStrings = new Set<String>{txtImportSection1, txtImportSection2,
    txtImportSection3, txtImportSection4, txtImportSection5, txtImportSection6};

givenStrings.removeAll(new Set<String>{null, '', ' '});

if(!givenStrings.isEmpty()){
    // do work
}
```

This approach does keep the `if()` condition nice and short, and we aren't repeating ourselves a lot. It does fall a bit short on the "principle of least surprise" though.

Comment: Nice way of looking at it. Just one question from my end, won't this be two Set getting initialized and taking up some memory? Just curious to know.

Comment: @NagendraSingh Yes, though the set with null, empty, and whitespace would be eligible for garbage collection pretty much immediately. Through some basic testing, the impact of `givenStrings` on the heap should be negligible (4 bytes for the set, 4 bytes per string, tested with 6 strings of length 100).

Comment: @DerekF I have below data in my string

Comment: UAP1 10WYL UA1 2022050400 01 100428724ALLWORTHY  NF13756960206081957 30000000N0Y497 NJ088227083 0 YKFI2137569602 019083108326 041120220 0 1010

Comment: still not all the reecords going inside if loop. I am sure that strings are not empty.

Comment: @SalesforceKid Then I'm afraid you'll need to provide more context and examples in your question by making an edit (or making a new question). With the information you've given us so far, this is about as much of as answer anyone will be able to give you.